# Does “Higher than 30% of stick A” include the full height of stick A and more?

Tags: mathematics

Let's assume I have a guide to cut 2 sticks

Stick A should has 100cm of length. Stick B should has length higher than 30% of stick A.

So if we calculate, 30% of stick A is 30cm.

Is it:

1. Stick A: 100cm, stick B = Stick A + (30% x Stick A) = 100 + 30% x 100 = 130cm. So Stick B must have length at least 130cm. (140cm, 150cm, and so on is OK)

or

2. Stick A: 100cm, stick B = higher than 30% of stick A. 30% of stick A is 30 cm, that means "higher than 30cm" could be 40cm, 50cm, and so on.

Comment: I think this is unanswerable in its present form: you are asking how to interpret an ambiguous formulation which is not idiomatic English. We would say "Stick A should be 100cm long" and either "Stick B should be (more than/at least) 30% longer than Stick A" or "Stick B should be (more than/at least) 30% of Stick A's length", depending on which meaning is intended. As you see, these ways of expressing it are unambiguous.

Comment: Which do you think is correct? Why? (I'm curious)

Comment: Who edited out the fact that the user is learning English? The fact that they are learning is why the question is ambiguous. Superfluous edit.

Comment: @lurker I agree; Nathan's edit was way overreaching.

Comment: No need to name names. Nathan works hard here.

Comment: @lurker: Pretty much everyone here is learning, so any further mention of that seems superfluous to me. "I am asking this question on this site because I don't know enough about the subject this site covers" can be taken for granted on almost every SE site in existence. (Exception: Code Golf, Puzzling, and probably one or two others.) I do try not to be too aggressive in my edits, but I don't think this one was mistaken. (I appreciate your deference, though.)

Comment: We always say "**should have**." Saying "should has" is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing measurements by saying stick B's **length** is **higher**. Either stick B's **length** is **longer** or stick B's **height** is **higher/taller**

Your two examples are

> **B is more / higher / longer than 30% of A**
>   A = 100
>   B = 0.3 x 100
>   B = 30
>   result: stick B needs to be 30 or more
>
> **B is 30% more / higher / longer than A**
>   A = 100
>   B = 1.3 x 100
>   B = 130
>   result: stick B needs to be 130 or more

Due to the position of the **relative size** phrase in relation to the **necessary proportion** in your question

B needs to be greater than 30